# Add \n every N characters in a query? 

Tags: sql-server-ce

Well this is the problem I return a column which is  a street (large)

For example I return next column

```
Street
C. 4 DE MARZO No. EXT LT 03 X MACHUXAC Y RETORNO 05 COL. PAYO OBISPO I Y II OTHON POMPEYO BLANCO QUINTANA ROO MEXICO
```

on my pocket pc app I watch

```
C. 4 DE MARZO No ...
```

(so when I put on this, I could see all street complete) but I need return it with '\n'
for add enters

I want every X characters (for example 15 characters)

it was added a '\n' which means a "enter" so when it was view on program it is not going
to appears all in a LINE

I am working on SQL Server CE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really strongly suggest you attempt to do this at the UI level.  Inserting formatting into DB queries is a recipe for problems down the road.

Comment: yes I  couldn't fin a solution on sqlce and my solution was on .net